# Getting the type of another nested class from the same "parent" class

Tags: c#, parameter-passing, nested-class

I'm attempting to make a namespace for the first time while learning programming.  I am hoping there is a way around the problem I've run into that isn't particularly messy, but essentially I have a class object that keeps two dictionaries of two nested class objects.  I need to be able to pass the Dictionary of NestedClassA to NestedClassB or to allow NestedClassB to access it in some way...  Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
namespace MyFirstNamespace 
{
    public class BossClass 
    {
        public Dictionary<int, NestedClassA> DictionaryA = new Dictionary<int, NestedClassA>();
        public Dictionary<int, NestedClassB> DictionaryB = new Dictionary<int, NestedClassB>();

        public class NestedClassA { ...arbitrary class definition... }

        public class NestedClassB 
        {
            public Dictionary<int, NestedClassA> PassedDictionary;

            public NestedClassB() { }

            public NestedClassB(Dictionary<int, NestedClassA> tempDic))
            {
                PassedDictionary = tempDic;
            }
        }


        public BossClass() { ... arbitrary constructor ... }

        ...arbitrary dictionary population methods...

        function void CreateAClassBInstance()
        {
            DictionaryB[n] = new NestedClassB(n, DictionaryA);
        }
    }
}
```

My problem seems to be that I can't typecast "NestedClassA" within "NestedClassB" because it doesn't recognize the type.  Is it possible to access the "NestedClassA" type within B?  Nothing I've tried has worked.  Do I have to pass the instance of "BossClass" so I can reference type by "`Dictionary<int, MyFirstNamespace.BossClassInstance.NestedClassA>`"?

Any help would be appreciated.  To be clear, I want a REFERENCE variable passed to NestedClassB of a Dictionary of all NestedClassA members so they can be manipulated by NestedClassB.  It can't be a clone.   I know this seems like ridiculous implementation, but it seems the most effective, if it's possible, for what I'm trying to do.

EDIT: maybe I shouldn't be nesting them at all, but it would make them much easier to serialize, which is why I really wanted to do it this way.

(EDIT - fixed typo where I forgot to insert "public" before constructors.)

Comment: Suggestion: as you are beginning programming, I suggest that you try one new thing at a time. Namespaces, ok, nesting, not necessary. Leave it until later.

Comment: That's not a particularly imprecise question in my view.  I'm certain I could make this work perfectly fine if the classes were not nested, and, henceforth, I would not be here asking this because what I would otherwise be attempting to do would be something I already know how to do.  What I don't seem to be able to do is have NestingClassB recognize NestingClassA's type.  I'm not particularly certain that typing "namespace xxxx" at the top of a list of class definitions is something that is overly taxing that I can't learn whether or not one can cross reference nested classes.

Comment: My current belief is that it needs direct access to the instantiation of "BossClass" due to the fact that BossClass is not static.  I was hoping there was a way around this, but I could pass the instance up from the calling solution if it's absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be anything particularly wrong with your implementation of NestedClassB other than you need to make your constructors public if you wish to instantiate an instance of NestedClassB. By default in .Net, objects are passed by reference to function parameters, so you will have the same instance of Dictionary<int, NestedClassA> in NestedClassB.

Here is the adjusted class:

```
    public class NestedClassB 
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<int, NestedClassA> _PassedDictionary;

        public NestedClassB() { }

        public NestedClassB(Dictionary<int, NestedClassA> tempDic) {
            _PassedDictionary = tempDic;
        }

        public Dictionary<int, NestedClassA> PassedDictionary {
            get { return _PassedDictionary; }
        }
    }
```

Note that I changed PassedDictionary to a property instead of a member variable. Most serializers will ignore member variables and only serialize properties. If you need to deserialize, you'll need to remove the readonly from the private member variable and add a setter.

The function at the bottom of your code snippet doesn't look right. You'll want to make it look like:

```
private void CreateAClassBInstance()
{
    DictionaryB[n] = new NestedClassB(DictionaryA);
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, that was just a mistake as I was typing it in.  The constructors all have public in them in the actual script, I was simply attempting to write a template for what my problem is.  The "Dictionary" declaration in NestingClassB says that "NestingClassA" is not a recognized "type or namespace" in the context of "NestingClassB."

Comment: In regards to the final code block you wrote, yes, that was incorrect.  I meant to put: 
NestedClassB tempClass = new NestedClassB(DictionaryA);
DictionaryB.Add(n, NestedClassB)

Regardless, as this isn't the actual code I have (which is 500 lines, hence, better left out and replaced with a template indicating my general problem]) and that code is otherwise correct, barring my nested class dilemma.

I will attempt to pass the instantiation of the "BossClass" to "NestedClassB".  Being new to C# I was not aware of the "this" keyword assuming the problem is not having a reference to the instance.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone trying to do this: passing the instance of the wrapper class is necessary for the nested class to access methods or variables of the wrapper class.  This can be done with "this" keyword.